# jQuery nextUntil() works weird with comment element

Tags: javascript, jquery, nextuntil

I need help. I have weird problem with jQuery's `nextUntil()` method. It is not working as I am expecting...

I have two comment tags inside my HTML which delimit the elements I am interested in and which I want to get into a jQuery collection. For that I first find both comment nodes, and apply `nextUntil` on the first, providing as argument the second. But `nextUntil` returns *all* of the children that follow the first comment, seemingly ignoring the argument I have passed to it.

How can I prevent this from happening, and get only the children *between* the two comments?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>

  <!-- from -->

  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>

  <!--  to  -->

  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
  const fromSign = 'from'
  const toSign = 'to'

  // filter callback - return only comment
  // element with specific text
  function commentWith (elm, txt) {
    return elm.nodeType === 8 &&
           elm.nodeValue.trim() === txt
  }

  // Step - 1 find comment with "from"
  // text and save returned element
  const $start = $('ul').contents().filter(
    (idx, elm) => commentWith(elm, fromSign)
  )

  // Find comment with "to"
  // text and save returned element
  const $stop = $('ul').contents().filter(
    (idx, elm) => commentWith(elm, toSign)
  )

  console.info($start, $stop) // So far, so good

  // Step 2 - find all elements
  // between "from" and "to" comments
  let $inner = $start.nextUntil($stop)

  // Not works - inner contains elements
  // beyond "to" comment
  console.log($inner)

  // Step 2 again - find all elements
  // between "from" and "to" comments
  // with "redundant" prev/next
  $inner = $start.nextUntil($stop.prev().next())

  // OK, just li 3 and 4,
  // but why? What am I missing?
  console.log($inner)
```

PS: If you use `<div class="from">` and `<div class="end">` or other elements to select start and end, `nextAll()` works as expected. But, I want use comments for marking the selection....

I tried with `prev`/`next` "hacks" as alternative (see also code above), but they don't behave well when there are no elements preceding and/or following the comment markers.

Comment: Using prev/next on element will not work if this element will be first, if there is no prev element. Then I must use next/prev. But next/prev on element will not work if this element will be last. This is the problem. It must work as expected, without those weird tricks.

Comment: I see. I will answer in a minute.

Comment: so... uhm... your question, needs a question or problem statement before the code.

Comment: If you can, please edit my question and make it more clear.

Comment: you never specified what your problem is, you just said something's weird... I can kinda guess at what it is (nextUntil looks at elements.. of course it's not gonna count comment nodes...) but since i'm not you i can't accurately generate a problem statement for you.

Comment: I specified question clearly, jQuery.nexUntil() not work with comment element...

Comment: I will edit the question to clear all doubts for Kevin, although he could have done it himself....

Comment: Ok trincot, please edit it. My english is really poor :(

Comment: Edited. Please review to see it correctly reflects what you wanted to say.

Comment: Good work, thank you.

Comment: Tested, works as expected, thank you again. Any quick idea how to make it more flexible? If there is no "to" comment, select all elements after "from" comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the first variant of your code fails is that most jQuery methods only look at *elements*, not nodes of other node types. As stated in the [jQuery documentation on `contents`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

> Please note that most jQuery operations don't support text nodes and comment nodes. The few that do will have an explicit note on their API documentation page.

In your case the call to `nextUntil` will step through elements only, not even looking at other nodes, and so it will "miss" the *$stop* node.

A workaround is to use `index()`. This will also work well when there are no elements before the start mark, and/or no elements after the stop mark. The index returned for a non-element node will be the index it *would* have if it *were* an element node.

```js
const fromSign = 'from'
const toSign = 'to'

// filter callback - return only comment
// element with specific text
function commentWith (elm, txt) {
    return elm.nodeType === 8 &&
           elm.nodeValue.trim() === txt
}

// Step - 1 find comment with "from"
// text and save returned index
const startIndex = $('ul').contents().filter(
    (idx, elm) => commentWith(elm, fromSign)
).index();

// Find comment with "to"
// text and save returned index
const stopIndex = $('ul').contents().filter(
    (idx, elm) => commentWith(elm, toSign)
).index();

console.log('indexes:', startIndex, stopIndex);

// Step 2 - get all child elements
// between "from" and "to" comments
let $inner = $('ul').children().slice(startIndex, stopIndex);

// Now it works - inner contains the elements between the markings
console.log('selected first and last text:', $inner.first().text(), $inner.last().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>

    <!-- from -->

    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>

    <!--  to  -->

    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what the problem is with this answer?

Comment: someone probably just likes poking bee hives.